# MultiDataSetIterator with INDArrays (not csv files) and multiple outputs DL4J

Tags: deeplearning4j, dl4j

I want to train a ComputationGraph which has two outputs ([this model](https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples/tree/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/convolution/alphagozero)) and in my script I have INDArrays (1 input and 2 outputs) ready to be sent in the neural network and it seems that I should use a MultiDataSetIterator to be able to setup batchsize before using the model.fit() function. I have been looking for a way to implement that for a long time and I have always found answers with CSV files but it is not what I want to use because while performing the simulations of the game I am creating a dataset of INDArrays that are stored in the memory and I am not loading any kind of CSV file.

Any ideas on how to create my MultiDataSetIterator to feed my fit() function ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the multidataset iterator. You can fit with a multidataset ([here](https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/deeplearning4j/nn/graph/ComputationGraph.html#fit-org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.api.MultiDataSet-)) or you can fit with arrays of ndarrays([here](https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/deeplearning4j/nn/graph/ComputationGraph.html#fit-org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray:A-org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray:A-)) using your ndarrays in memory.

Comment: Thanks ! I will try this. But I don't see how I can manage the batch size with these methods